# WinForms Фильтрация таблицы в datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Как можно отфильтровать таблицу (не касаясь самой бд) в datagridview, чтобы показывались, например, только те строки, у которых значения в определенном столбике больше 100?

Comment: написать запрос с условием и результат поместить в dgv, это самое простое, но вроде у dgv есть какие-то фильтры (мб функция Filter или что-то типо того, но не уверен). Или "не касаясь бд" подразумевает не делать запросы к бд?

Comment: Именно, мне не нужно делать запросы к бд. Тут работа только лишь с dgv

Comment: хм, вряд ли я помогу, но думаю надо добавить код, где ты датагридвью заполняешь данными, отредактируй вопрос

Comment: Данные в чём хранятся? DataTable, типизированный список? Вот его и фильтруйте.

Comment: В продолжение комментария про DataTable - вот несколько полезных ссылок, которые могут вам помочь https://10tec.com/articles/datagridview-filter.aspx https://stackoverflow.com/a/13012669/13123688